# How to check if a link has been clicked then close a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have a function that opens a modal and displays error messages in that dialog based on a condition as follows

```
  Error: function (ex, context) {
       
        var current = $(".Capture[dataid=" + context + "]");
          current.addClass('error');
       if(ex)
       var link='http://localhost/test'
        current.append(`<div class="error">please click on the link <a href = "${link}">Details</a></div>`);

    },
```

so as you can see i add a link to be displayed on the dialog,but how do i determine when the user clicks on the link? and then  i want it to invoke a button click
which is

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix"><div class="ui-dialog-buttonset"><button type="button">Close</button></div></div>
```

so that it would end up invoking  the dialog Close option

```
 $(dialog).dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    closeOnEscape: false,
                    dialogClass: "noClose",
                    height: $(window).height() * 0.8,
                    buttons: {
                        "Close": function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    },
                    close: function (event) {
                       //does something in here
                       
                    },
                   
                });
```

so basically when a link is clicked it will redirect you to that page and close the dialog for you.

Comment: Hi, can you make this runnable ?

Comment: Hi, i did try, but its not working out,cause i have to many things thats required to set it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write click event on `a` tag so whenever this tag is clicked get `href` of `a` tag then use `.trigger('click')` to trigger click event on close button and finally redirect to required page.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("#dialog").dialog({
  modal: true,
  closeOnEscape: false,
  dialogClass: "noClose",
  height: $(window).height() * 0.8,
  buttons: {
    "Close": function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
      console.log(" I am in")
    }
  },
  close: function(event) {
    //does something in here

  },

});

//on click of a tag
$(document).on("click", ".error a", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr("href") //get href
  $(".ui-dialog-buttonset button").trigger('click'); //trigger click event on close button
  window.location.href = href;
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
Here is dialog.
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <div class="error">please click on the link
    <a href="google.com">Details</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly got what do You want - try this:

```
$('a').on('click', (e) => 
   { 
      e.preventDefault();
      $('button')[0].click();
   });
```